# my function makes it where i cannot do anything unless i restart the program

Tags: python, tkinter, gpio

```
from tkinter import *
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import sys




DHTPIN = 14

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW)
MAX_UNCHANGE_COUNT = 100

STATE_INIT_PULL_DOWN = 1
STATE_INIT_PULL_UP = 2
STATE_DATA_FIRST_PULL_DOWN = 3
STATE_DATA_PULL_UP = 4
STATE_DATA_PULL_DOWN = 5

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW)

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("700x700")
root.title("House Control")

cur_temp = 70
counter = Tkinter.IntVar()
def toggle29():
  if GPIO.input(21):
    GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW)
    toggleButton29["text"] = "Turn BLUE 29 On"
  else:
    GPIO.output(21, GPIO.HIGH)
    toggleButton29["text"] = "Turn BLUE 29 Off"

def system_state():
        if on_btn.config('text')[-1] == 'On':
            on_btn.config(text='Off')

        else:
            on_btn.config(text='On')

def system_ac_state():    
    if ac_btn.config('text')[-1] == 'Cooling': 
        ac_btn.config(text='Heating')
        ac_heating()
        main()
    else:
    ac_btn.config(text='Cooling')
    ac_cooling()

def ac_heating():
    print("heating")
    pass
def ac_cooling():
    print("cooling")
    pass

def cool_temp():
    print ("cooling")

def heat_temp():
    print ("heating")

def onClick1(event=None):
    counter.set(counter.get() - 1)

def onClick(event=None):
    counter.set(counter.get() + 1)

def toggle0():
  if GPIO.input(17):
    GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)
    toggleButton0["text"] = "Turn RED 0 On"
  else:
    GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)
     toggleButton0["text"] = "Turn RED 0 Off"

 def read_dht11_dat():
     GPIO.setup(DHTPIN, GPIO.OUT)
     GPIO.output(DHTPIN, GPIO.HIGH)
     time.sleep(0.05)
     GPIO.output(DHTPIN, GPIO.LOW)
     time.sleep(0.02)
     GPIO.setup(DHTPIN, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP)

     unchanged_count = 0
     last = -1
     data = []
     while True:
         current = GPIO.input(DHTPIN)
         data.append(current)
         if last != current:
             unchanged_count = 0
             last = current
         else:
             unchanged_count += 1
             if unchanged_count > MAX_UNCHANGE_COUNT:
                 break

     state = STATE_INIT_PULL_DOWN

     lengths = []
     current_length = 0

     for current in data:
         current_length += 1

         if state == STATE_INIT_PULL_DOWN:
         if current == GPIO.LOW:
             state = STATE_INIT_PULL_UP
         else:
             continue
     if state == STATE_INIT_PULL_UP:
         if current == GPIO.HIGH:
             state = STATE_DATA_FIRST_PULL_DOWN
         else:
             continue
     if state == STATE_DATA_FIRST_PULL_DOWN:
         if current == GPIO.LOW:
             state = STATE_DATA_PULL_UP
         else:
             continue
     if state == STATE_DATA_PULL_UP:
         if current == GPIO.HIGH:
             current_length = 0
             state = STATE_DATA_PULL_DOWN
         else:
             continue
     if state == STATE_DATA_PULL_DOWN:
         if current == GPIO.LOW:
             lengths.append(current_length)
             state = STATE_DATA_PULL_UP
         else:
             continue
 if len(lengths) != 40:
     print ("Data not good, skip")
     return False

 shortest_pull_up = min(lengths)
 longest_pull_up = max(lengths)
 halfway = (longest_pull_up + shortest_pull_up) / 2
 bits = []
 the_bytes = []
 byte = 0

 for length in lengths:
     bit = 0
     if length > halfway:
         bit = 1
     bits.append(bit)
 print ("bits: %s, length: %d") % (bits, len(bits))
 for i in range(0, len(bits)):
     byte = byte << 1
     if (bits[i]):
         byte = byte | 1
     else:
         byte = byte | 0
     if ((i + 1) % 8 == 0):
         the_bytes.append(byte)
         byte = 0
 print (the_bytes)
 checksum = (the_bytes[0] + the_bytes[1] + the_bytes[2] + the_bytes[3]) & 
0xFF
 if the_bytes[4] != checksum:
     print ("Data not good, skip")
     return False

 return the_bytes[0], the_bytes[2]
```

When this def main runs it locks up my whole program.
I need to be able to get information from it so i can use the information for an if and when statement. So how do i run this script and not lock up my entire script?

```
def main():
    print ("Raspberry Pi wiringPi DHT11 Temperature test program\n")
    while True:
        result = read_dht11_dat()
        if result:
            humidity, temperature= result
            temp = (temperature * 9/5)+32     
            test = 73
            low = temp >= test
            print ("humidity: %s %%,  Temperature: %s C (F %s)") % 
(humidity, temperature, temp)
            if low:
              while True:  
                GPIO.output(21,GPIO.HIGH)
                print ("humidity: %s  r %s c %s") % (humidity, temperature, 
temp)
                continue
            else:
                GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW)
            print ("1humidity: %s ") % (low)
        time.sleep(1)
        continue

def destroy():
    GPIO.cleanup()    

toggleButton0 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="0 Carport Lights", 
command=toggle0, foreground="white", background="red")
toggleButton0.grid(row=0,column=0)    
Tkinter.Label(root, text="Current Temperature").grid(row=0, column=1)    
Tkinter.Label(root, text=cur_temp).grid(row=1, column=1)
Tkinter.Label(root, text="Desired Temperature").grid(row=0, column=2)     
Tkinter.Label(root, textvariable=counter).grid(row=1, column=2)
Tkinter.Button(root, text="Increase", command=onClick, fg="dark green", bg = 
"white").grid(row=1, column=3)
Tkinter.Button(root, text="Decrease", command=onClick1, fg="dark green", bg 
= "white").grid(row=1, column=0)
Tkinter.Label(root, text="You are using :").grid()
ac_btn = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Heating", command=system_ac_state, 
fg="dark green", bg = "white")
ac_btn.grid()
Tkinter.Button(root, text="Main", command=main, fg="dark green", bg = 
"white").grid(row=2, column=1)
Tkinter.Label(root, text="Turn System:").grid()
```

when run the application will check the state of the system and if its on then it will check the system_ac_state and use variables from the main script to control the gpio.

```
on_btn = Tkinter.Button(root, text="On", command=system_state, fg="dark 
green", bg = "white")
on_btn.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ok i didn’t read that wall of code but looking at main, if you’re running that infinite while loop on the main thread then of course it will lock up.. idk the context here but thinking you should run it on a separate thread OR use a coroutine instead.. but for sure it’s getting stuck in the inner while loop cus it has no condition to exit

Comment: Once the inner `while True` is entered, it will never exit. Is that `continue` supposed to be a `break`?

Comment: @mad.meesh: Separate threads generally being a bad idea in `tkinter` based code (it's possible to do it, but if you try to interact with the UI, bad things happen).

Comment: ok i see.. well like i said , it’s getting stuck in the inner while i believe, there’s no exit condition

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Same goes for the outer `while True:` for that matter. And using `time.sleep` in `tkinter` code is just asking for UI freezes; you need to have a design where you are invoked by the `tkinter` `mainloop`, and intermittently reschedule yourself to run later with `after` or `after_idle`, you can't just have an imperative loop that never yields control back to the event loop.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: separate threads are fine, you just shouldn't modify the GUI from more than one thread. If you follow that simple rule, threads can be used quite safely.

Comment: @mad.meesh thank you and ok is there an option you recommend beside tkinter for this sort of thing that would function like im wanting. and the jist of the app is its a thermostat control and gpio controller its got a long way to go but im trying.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Agreed in theory. But the OP clearly doesn't understand `tkinter` design yet, and it's probably a bad idea for them to add threading when they don't understand how to work with the event loop in the first place.

Comment: ok @Carcigenicate i will look into that and see if i can figure it out running it with after or after_idle.

Comment: @user3802783: Almost all GUI toolkits have similar restrictions; all code must either run via the event loop (handing back control after requesting it be invoked in the future, not just sleeping), or must run in a separate thread (and is therefore not allowed to modify the UI). Leaving `tkinter` won't help here. GUI code is innately cooperatively singlethreaded, so you either cooperate on the UI thread, or you offload non-GUI work to a worker thread.

Comment: @ShadowRanger ok i appreciate all the responses at least now i know what to study a read about to try to gain a better understanding. Thank you all or your input.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: yes, but we shouldn't be giving them misleading information.